# Asterisk Dialplan Functionality

Tags: asterisk

I was wondering if anyone knows if the following is possible using an asterisk dialplan, and if so, where i'd find the info to program it.

1) Agent dials extension e.g. 1234

2) Agents DND Status is toggled on/off
3) MWI changed to reflect DND status, if DND MWI on

4) Update MySql DB to keep a record of what times status was changed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I did not misunderstand your intentions, and the following code will give you some inspiration.

```
[ext-local-custom]
exten => 1234,1,Answer()
; Ask agent to input action
; 1 - enable DND
; 0 - disable DND
exten => 1234,n(input),Read(digito,enter-toggled-on-off,1)
exten => 1234,n,GotoIf($["foo${digito}"="foo1"]?toggledOn)
exten => 1234,n,GotoIf($["foo${digito}"="foo0"]?toggledOff)
exten => 1234,n,Playback(invalid)
exten => 1234,n,Goto(input)
exten => 1234,n(toggledOn),NoOP(section toggled On)
; Set DND ON
exten => 1234,n,Set(DB(DND/${CALLERID(number)})=YES)
; MySQL record action
exten => 1234,n,MySql(connect connid localhost root  test)
exten => 1234,n,MySql(query resultidr ${connid} INSERT INTO `test`.`togglelog` (`exten`\,`toggle`\,`logtime`)VALUES (\'${CALLERID(number)}\'\,1\,\'${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}\'))
exten => 1234,n,Goto(end)
exten => 1234,n(toggledOff),NoOP(section toggled Off)
; Set DND Off
exten => 1234,n,DBdel(DND/${CALLERID(number)})
; MySQL record action
exten => 1234,n,MySql(connect connid localhost root  test)
exten => 1234,n,MySql(query resultidr ${connid} INSERT INTO `test`.`togglelog` (`exten`\,`toggle`\,`logtime`)VALUES (\'${CALLERID(number)}\'\,0\,\'${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}\'))
exten => 1234,n,Goto(end)
exten => 1234,n(end),Hangup()
```

Comment: Please, not use mysql deprecated command when give answers. User realtime instead of that.

Comment: Hi, arheops. I'm new to asterisk. I'm not sure if your "realtime" is Function READTIME.

WIKI says that REALTIME can read and update, but cannot insert.
"REALTIME(....) will read names/values from the repository."
"REALTIME(....)= will write a new value/field to the repository. "

Please correct me if I misunderstood your meaning.

Comment: REALTIME can insert. See REALTIME_STORE function. Why you answering questions if you are not expert? Function MySQL can loose connections and not availible in asterisk 11.

Comment: OMG, I have no hostility. I am still using version 1.4 because of work, and I touch asterisk less than half a year. So there are too many things I do not know. "REALTIME_STORE" is available since 1.6, I'll never known it without you tell me. Thank you for pointing out "REALTIME_STORE", and please forgive me if I have offended you. My English is REALLY POOR, possible errors express what I mean.

Comment: Anyway, Mysql depricated even in 1.4. So please use func_odbc or Realtime in your future dialplans.

Comment: Thanks. I just viewed func_realtime.c of version 1.6.2.24, I'll try to transplant it to version 1.4.31 tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, arheops. I failed to transplant "REALTIME_STORE" to version 1.4.31. Instead I compiled func_odbc.so and res_odbc.so, and they seems work well. Thanks for your guidance.